# Feltring two views block with one filter

Tags: filter, drupal-7, view

I am using Drupal 7. I would like to filter two view blocks with one filter.

I found a module named [Views Global Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter), but still not know exactly how it works.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried yet.

Comment: Thank you i'm new in drupal i just activate the module but i dont know  how can i work with : the module create tow blocks in blocks but i dont know how to use theme ..

Answer (score 0):

You may use contextual filters to filter the blocks by given some values in the url. For example: add taxonomy id in the url, then you may filter the block.